# Layout view stuck after snackbar appears with coordinator view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-snackbar

I've managed to get a snackbar show successfully using a coordinator layout wrapped around a MapView in a fragment. The map view successfully slides up to allow room for the snackbar, however, once the snackbar has gone, the view stays were it is and leaves a white bar where the snackbar would appear. How can I fix this? I'm currently applying the following code as a behavior on the map view:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        // we only want to trigger the change
        // only when the changes is from a snackbar
        return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
    }
```

and my fragments view is this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/places_coordinator_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.adamshort.canieatthis.FloatingActionButtonBehaviour"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried searching around, but either I'm searching for the wrong thing or I no one's had a similar issue. I've seen the behavior code I have posted and working successfully in various tutorials and videos, but it doesn't behave well with the map view. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should add "app:layout_behavior="com.adamshort.canieatthis.FloatingActionButtonBehaviour" to your floating action button... and not to MapView

Comment: @GuilhermeP it's a custom behavior to imitate what happens to the floating button. The whole point of it is to apply custom behaviors to other views, thats just the name I gave it as it will replicate the FAB.

Comment: Sorry... You right... Forget it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended by Google to prevent interfering with accessibility operation.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209953

Answer (score 0):

Please, my answer below is an attempt to help you... Let me know if it helps you or not... Then, I delete if it is useless...

Maybe, you need to define and anchor to your MapView. In my case, I had to created a dummy view in the bottom and set it as archor to the view which will move with the SnackBar

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/places_coordinator_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/anchor"
            app:layout_behavior="com.adamshort.canieatthis.FloatingActionButtonBehaviour"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Nope same, issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem.

To fix this I changed the onDependentViewChanged() method to store the initial Y position of the view this behaviour is attached to. Then on removal of the snackbar, which calls the onDependentViewRemoved() method, reset the position of that view to the stored Y position.

```
private static float initialPositionY;

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
    initialPositionY = child.getY();
    float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
    child.setTranslationY(translationY);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDependentViewRemoved(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
    super.onDependentViewRemoved(parent, child, dependency);
    child.setTranslationY(initialPositionY);
}
```

Comment: child.setTranslationY(0) is what you need to do in onDependentViewRemoved to reset the position to its original position. setTranslationY moves a view relative to its top position (view.getTop()), so setTranslationY(0) moves it back to the top position.